# Trying to use stockstats to cal rsi, getting error "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Tags: python

I'm tryng to cal the rsi of a set of test data.
This is what I do

1. create a data frame of the test data

   `df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'adj close'])`
2. make the data frame into a webstate frame

   `stock_df = Sdf.retype(df)`
3. cal the `rsdata['rsi']=stock_df['rsi_14']`

complete error message and code
"C:\Users\tpottel\programming\java\eclipse projects\BBitBotCoinUsing2\pythonpro\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:/Users/tpottel/programming/java/eclipse projects/BBitBotCoinUsing2/pythonpro/webstats/webstats.py"
C:\Users\tpottel\programming\java\eclipse projects\BBitBotCoinUsing2\pythonpro\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:189: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)

(sample code on internet http://pythondata.com/stockstats-python-module-various-stock-market-statistics-indicators/ )
CODE:

```
import pandas as pd
import stockstats as st
from stockstats import StockDataFrame as Sdf
#from pandas.io import data, wb # becomes
#from pandas_datareader import data, wb

data=[[567, 700, 650, 710, 760, 1, 670]]

data.append([567, 700, 650, 710, 760, 1, 670])
data.append([567, 700, 650, 710, 760, 1, 670])
data.append([567, 700, 650, 710, 760, 1, 670])
data.append([567, 700, 650, 710, 760, 1, 670])
data.append([567, 700, 650, 710, 760, 1, 670])
data.append([567, 700, 650, 710, 760, 1, 670])
data.append([567, 700, 650, 710, 760, 1, 670])
data.append([567, 700, 650, 710, 760, 1, 670])
data.append([567, 700, 650, 710, 760, 1, 670])
data.append([567, 700, 650, 710, 760, 1, 670])
data.append([567, 700, 650, 710, 760, 1, 670])
data.append([567, 700, 650, 710, 760, 1, 670])
data.append([567, 700, 650, 710, 760, 1, 670])
data.append([567, 700, 650, 710, 760, 1, 670])
data.append([567, 700, 650, 710, 760, 1, 670])
data.append([567, 700, 650, 710, 760, 1, 670])
data.append([567, 700, 650, 710, 760, 1, 670])

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'adj close'])
```

stock_df = Sdf.retype(df)
df['rsi']=stock_df['rsi_14']

Comment: `data` is a list. What do you think `data['rsi']` should do?

Comment: There is not even any such thing as `'rsi_14'` in your whole code. Moreover data is a list, not a dataframe

Comment: hi I changed it to

Comment: I changed it to stock_df = Sdf.retype(df)
df['rsi']=stock_df['rsi_14'] On the sample code they use rsi_14 whitch stands for Relative Strength Index